# @protocol vs Class Cluster

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ios

What are those major *pro* and *contra* for `@protocol` and [Class Clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) concepts in Objective-C ?

Both of them introduce [Loose Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling) in program architecture. Are they conceptually almost equal, or is there something else worth to know ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caveat: Not a cocoa pro, but I don't believe they are equal at all.

With [Class Clusters](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) you subclass.

> Class clusters are a design pattern that the Foundation framework makes extensive use of. Class clusters group a number of private concrete subclasses under a public abstract superclass. The grouping of classes in this way simplifies the publicly visible architecture of an object-oriented framework without reducing its functional richness. Class clusters are based on the Abstract Factory design pattern discussed in “Cocoa Design Patterns.”

[`@protocols`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW46) on the other hand, are more like Java interfaces.

> The Objective-C extension called a protocol is very much like an interface in Java. Both are simply a list of method declarations publishing an interface that any class can choose to implement. The methods in the protocol are invoked by messages sent by an instance of some other class.

In short, Class Clusters are subclass/superclass where the subclass conforms to the entire identity of the superclass so that the implementation can be hidden from the user.  This is apparent in the case of `NSArray` where the compiler uses context to choose the best type of data structure to use.  You don't call `NSTree` or `NSLinkedList` like you might in Java.  You can see how `NSNumber` is [implemented here](http://code.google.com/p/purefoundation/source/browse/trunk/NSNumber.m?r=30), especially the part where it says:

> // NSNumber instance methods -- which will never be called...

@protocols are like client/server relationship where the client class adopts a protocol of the server class, so the server can call functionality on the client.  `<NSAppDelegate>` and [`<UIAlertViewDelegate>`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html) are great examples of the use of protocols.

Comment: Nice answer!  Java was derived quite directly from Objective-C, but @protocol came about after Java with the intention of capturing an interface-in-the-java-sense like functionality. (IIRC).

Comment: @bbum, I wasn't aware that Java was derived from Obj-C.  The shift to strong-typing changes massive portions of the OOP.

Comment: Yup -- you'll likely find this interesting: http://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/stuff/java-objc.html

Comment: @bbum, that's really cool.  Now I have something to show all those Java people that think Obj-C is inferior or useless.

Comment: @Stephen thanks for good explanation, and especially for **purefoundation** project link. @bbum: great excursion to the Obj-C and Java history !

Comment: @Martin, glad I could help.  I'm sure there's more subtlety to it than what I've described, but it should help you use them correctly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'd used protocol in Obj-C before working on my first Java 1.0 project so it would have had to come in Oak. Great link @bbum on the connection b/w the two languages. It also confirms that interface was "a direct rip-off of Obj-C's 'protocol'".